# How do i make a function in my .bash_profile accept input from stdin using pipe |

Tags: linux, bash, unix

say i have a function of this nature in my .bash_profile

```
sayword(){
   echo $1
}
```

now the command will be run like `sayword hello`
now i want the function to be able to  take input from other command using  unix pipe. something  like `cat words.txt | sayword` and it outputs each of the word in words.txt. How do i do that ?. I read a question here that talks about redirecting to dev/null but that doesn't seem to work .

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way

```sh
function sayword() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    while read input; do
      echo $input
    done
  else
    echo $1
  fi
}
```

and then you can call it like this

```
date | sayword
```

Comment: while this is helpful , it looks like i can call it this way ``` sayword hello``` anymore , i need such flexibility . i appreciate your answer anyways , thanks alot

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your needs, check if it helps

Comment: If you call this as `sayword 1 2 3` it only repeats `1`.  If you want all inputs on one line, use `echo "$@"`. If you want them output on separate lines, use `printf "%s\n" "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you want the `-t` condition: that can test if stdin is a pipe/redirection or the terminal (i.e. interactive):

```sh
sayword() {
  {
    echo "$(date) - saying words"
    if [ -t 0 ]; then
      # stdin is the terminal: take input from the cmdline parameters:
      echo "$*"
    else
      # stdin is a pipe or redirection
      cat
    fi
  } >> "$HOME/words.txt"
}
```

Then, these both append to the file:

```sh
$ sayword hello
$ cat ~/words.txt
Thu May 28 09:22:27 EDT 2020 - saying words
hello
```

```sh
$ echo foo bar | sayword
$ cat ~/words.txt
Thu May 28 09:22:27 EDT 2020 - saying words
hello
Thu May 28 09:22:37 EDT 2020 - saying words
foo bar
```